# How to open a webpage inside a div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, iframe

I want to open a webpage `main.html`, which is located in same directory of `index.html`.

Now using iframe, it is opening but I don't want to use iframe or any other script except Javascript.

Also, I'm using this in Apache Cordova Windows app, so it doesn't allow using
 iframe or other related ways.

Comment: Please show the contents of main.js and index.js

Comment: i dont think if there is any need of my main.js and index.js. and my both scripts have much extra things so will be difficult to understand .Please just tell me the simple way to do my task :)

Comment: Sorry my bad, i meant the html, index.html and main.html....

Answer (score 1):

If you use `JQuery` use this:

```
$.get( "main.html", function( data ) {
  $( "#divID" ).html( data );
});
```